# Maximal Inequality for Expectation of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n$ be non-negative random variables, not necessarily independent. Then, show the expectation of the product of the random variables is less than or equal to the integral of the product of the quantile functions.

In other words, show that $$\mathbb{E}(Z_1Z_2...Z_n) \leq \int_{0}^{1} Q_{Z_1}(u)Q_{Z_2}(u)...Q_{Z_n}(u)~du,$$ where $Q_{Z_{i}}$ is the quantile function of $Z_i$.

The only way I currently see to establish the inequality for the expectation is by using Holding's inequality. But I'm not sure how to proceed with using the quantile functions. I'm guessing I need to use Fubini-Tonelli at some point.

Comment: Do they follow the same distribution?

Comment: Not necessarily, the variables may not follow the same distribution. However, if them following the same distribution helps to make some progress, that would help!

Comment: In general, if $X$ is a random variable and $U \sim U(0, 1)$, then $Q(U) \sim X$. So $E(X) = \int_{0}^{1}Q(u)\,du$.

Comment: @Mason, moreover, for any random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2\cdots X_n) = \int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_0^1 Q_{X_1}(u_1)\cdots Q_{X_n}(u_n) C(du_1,\dots,du_n),
$$
where $C$ is a certain copula. The OP claim is that this expression is maximal for the upper Fréchet–Hoeffding copula (when the variables are comonotone), which is kind of obvious, but it's not clear at all how to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem,
$$
\mathbb E\left(\prod_{j=1}^nZ_j\right)=\int_{(0,\infty)^n}\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^n\{Z_j>t_j\}\right)dt_1\dots dt_n.
$$
Using $\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_j\right)\leqslant \min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\mathbb P(A_j)$, we derive that
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb E\left(\prod_{j=1}^nZ_j\right)\leqslant \int_{(0,\infty)^n} \min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\mathbb P\left( \{Z_j>t_j\}\right)dt_1\dots dt_n.
$$
By definition of the quantile function, for a random variable $X$ and $t>0$,  $t<Q_X(u)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb P(X>t)> u$. Therefore, for each $u\in (0,1)$,
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\left\{t_j<Q_{Z_j}(u)\right\}}=\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\left\{\mathbb P(Z_j>t_j)> u\right\}}=\mathbf{1}_{\{\min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\mathbb P(Z_j>t_j)> u\}}
$$
and integrating over $u\in (0,1)$, we find
$$
\int_0^1\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\left\{t_j<Q_{Z_j}(u)\right\}}du=\min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\mathbb P(\{Z_j>t_j\}).
$$
Plug this into (*) to conclude.

Comment: Very nice! Also it is easy to see that $\mathrm P(\bigcap \dots) = \min \mathrm P(\dots)$ for all $t$'s iff the variables are comonotone.

Comment: I don't see how $t < Q_X(u) \iff \mathbb P(X > t) \leq u$. First, $t < Q_X(u) \iff \mathbb P(X \leq t) < u$. If it is also true that $\mathbb P(X > t) \leq u$, we would then have $\mathbb 1 = P(X \leq t) + \mathbb P(X > t) \leq 2u \iff u \geq 1/2$...

Comment: @AisforAmbition Indeed, we do have $t < Q_X(u) \iff \mathbb P(X \leq t) < u$. I have edited, thanks for the catch.